# Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple contact submission form with Jquery validation script that should tell the user if the there submission was successful or failed and display an error. The problem I am having is the submission is going through, but I am not receiving the validation message. Here is the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/62dj5/

```
            <form class="cmxform" id="CommentForm" method="post" action="#">
                    <input type="text" name="ContactName" id="ContactName" placeholder="Name" />         
                    <input type="text" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail" placeholder="Email" />     
                    <input type="text" name="ContactNumber" id="ContactNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" />         
                    <input type="text" name="ContactCompany" id="ContactCompany" placeholder="Company Name" />      
                    <input type="text" name="EventCity"  id="EventCity" placeholder=" Event City" />         
                    <input type="text" name="EventState" id="EventState"  placeholder="Event State" />          
                <p class="text">  
                    <textarea name="ContactComment" id="ContactComment" placeholder="Enter your message here"></textarea>  
                </p>  
                <p class="submit">  
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" />  
                </p>  
                <label id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." id="LoadingGraphic" /></label>
                <input class="" type="hidden" name="subject" value="Website Contact Form" />
            </form>  



            result = '';
            c = '';
            if (response === 'success') { 
                result = 'Your message has been sent. Thank you!';  
                c = 'success';
            } else {
                result = response;
                c = 'error';
            }

            note.removeClass('success').removeClass('error').text('');
            var i = setInterval(function() {
                if ( !note.is(':visible') ) {
                    note.html(result).addClass(c).slideDown('fast');
                    clearInterval(i);
                }
            }, 40);
```

Comment: Your success message must be inside of `success: function(response) {......}`

Comment: Your example is huge... can you condense it down into a more concise demonstration of the issue.  The form does not have to look good in order to be functional for the purposes of demonstration.  Also, you are using v1.6 and the jQuery Validate plugin is up to 1.10.

Comment: And finally, you don't have jQuery selected within [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62dj5/).  See "choose framework" options on the left: http://jsfiddle.net/Vt6qX/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a example just to give you an example of how validation can be done. It looks like you have two different forms referenced in your script; `#CommentForm` and `#subscribeForm` so it's very unclear as to what you are trying to do which makes helping with your submission issue difficult.

Here's the full code for the example I put on jsfiddle. Keep in mind this is for reference, cutting and pasting this example will not resolve your issue (especially since it looks like you're trying to output a success/fail message after your server-side validation occurs). Please take some time to review the documentation at [jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```js
$('#CommentForm').validate({
  errorClass: 'validation-error',
  rules: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    phone: {
      required: true,
      phoneUS: true
    },
    company: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    },
    city: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    },
    state: {
      required: true,
      stateUS: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    message: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 20
    }
  },
  messages: {
    name: {
      required: "Please enter your full name!"
    },
    email: {
      required: "Please enter your email!",
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    phone: {
      required: "Please enter your phone!"
    },
    company: {
      required: "Please enter your company!"
    },
    city: {
      required: "Please enter your city!"
    },
    state: {
      required: "Please enter your state!"
    },
    message: {
      required: "Please enter a short message!"
    }
  }
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
  var validator = $("#CommentForm").validate();
  validator.resetForm();
});
```

```css
input,
.form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
textarea {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}
.form-control:focus {
  background-color: rgba(74, 185, 255, 0.55);
  border-color: #33342e;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.2);
}
.form-control {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #4AB9FF;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
.btn-clear {
  color: #378ABF;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #42A6E5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
}
.btn-clear:hover,
.btn-clear:focus,
.btn-clear:active,
.btn-clear.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-clear {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #E80046;
  border-color: #1c1c1c;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
}
.btn-clear:active,
.btn-clear.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-clear {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-send {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #63C1D6;
  border-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
}
.btn-send:hover,
.btn-send:focus,
.btn-send:active,
.btn-send.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-send {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #035061;
  border-color: #1c1c1c;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
}
.btn-send:active,
.btn-send.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-send {
  background-image: none;
}
label.validation-error {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(245, 12, 12, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input.validation-error,
textarea.validation-error,
select.validation-error {
  border: 1px solid #f53660;
}
.alert {
  padding: 10px 5px 20px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #f53660;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.alert.info {
  background: #3194b1;
}
.alert.success {
  background: #749958;
}
.alert.error {
  background: #b55454;
}
.alert.warning {
  background: #978c68;
}
.alert i {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.alert.info i {
  color: #fff;
}
.alert.success i {
  color: #fff;
}
.alert.error i {
  color: #fff;
}
.alert.warning i {
  color: #fff;
}
#formstatus {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
label.validation-error {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(245, 12, 12, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input.validation-error,
textarea.validation-error,
select.validation-error {
  border: 1px solid #f53660;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form class="clearfix" id="CommentForm" name="CommentForm" method="post" action="php/comment.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Full Name">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Telephone">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--endrow-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="company" value="" placeholder="Company">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" value="" placeholder="City">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="state" value="" placeholder="State">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" value="" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message..."></textarea>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="btn btn-send" type="submit" value="Send">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="btn btn-clear" type="reset" id="reset" onClick="CommentForm.reset();" value="Clear Form" readonly>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end row-->
    <div id="formstatus"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```